# requested URL was not found on this server using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

When getting URL via firebase deploy --only hosting and use it, it work well and open the website, but when try put api/send like this Url: **https://*******.web.app/api/send** give me this error **

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

and i try post url in postman and it show that error

**JavaScript code **

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var MESSAGING_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
var SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router(); 
var request = require('request');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
router.post('/send', function(req, res){
getAccessToken().then(function(access_token){
    var title = req.body.title; 
    var body = req.body.body; 
    var token = req.body.token; 
    request.post({
        headers:{
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+access_token
        }, 
        url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/el-ma3sra/messages:send", 
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                "message":{
                    "token" : token,
                    "notification" : {
                        "body" : body,
                        "title" : title,
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }, function(error, response, body){
        res.end(body);
        console.log(body);
    });
});
});
app.use('/api', router);


function getAccessToken(){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var key = require("./service-account.json");
    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email,
        null,
        key.private_key,
        SCOPES,
        null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens){
        if(err){
            reject(err);
            return; 
        }
        resolve(tokens.access_token);
      });
  });
}

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"rewrites":[
  {
    "source":"/api/send",
    "function":"api"
  }
],
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
]
 }
```

}

i want solve my error

Comment: You should have the right url in the firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/XXXXXXXXXX/functions

Comment: Try to remove everything inside `router.post('/send', function(req, res) { }`, put some `console.log` there and check if it works.

Comment: if i writed console.log("") what should to do for test it

Answer (score 0):

I think you configured the following API url
`https://*******.web.app/api/api/send`

The first api comes from your export (`exports.api = ...`) the second api comes from your express application where you assigned your router to start at api (`app.use('/api'...`)

So maybe try to assign your router at root path

`app.use('/', ... )`

Comment: I tried delete api from app.use() and not solved the error

Comment: Why do you deploy using `firebase deploy --only hosting`? Have you even checked if your function is deployed in your firebase console? It might be that you only deployed your hosting but not your functions

Comment: Because when use firebase deploy ask me to transfer to billing account Blaze i don't want this

Comment: If this is the problem is there a solution without transfer my Firebase account to Blaze?

Comment: But have you ever deployed your function? If you deploy `--only hosting` and never deployed your function then there is no function. That would explain your error `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Comment: You need to understand hosting provides your static files (like html or images) functions provides your backend logic. I don't know of you can go without blaze. I am running on blaze but it is still 0,00$ per month

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the reason for the error

Comment: You can be sure if you look in your firebase console (I provided a link above). Check if your function `api` is listed there. If it is not that's your problem